# Android: onBindViewHolder() displays list of books twice from website

Tags: java, android, list, android-viewholder

I m writing simple android app - book finder from website

For "java" keyword the app returns 10 books on first page. But it **allows me to scroll this list twice!** I see books repeated.
[image: list]

```
public class BookRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookImageViewHolder> {

private List<Book>booksList ;
private Context context;
private final String LOG_TAG = BookRecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BookImageViewHolder bookImageViewHolder, int i) {              
        Book book = booksList.get(i);

        Picasso.with(context).load(book.getImageURL())
                .error(R.drawable.book_placeholder_image)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.book_placeholder_image)
                .into(bookImageViewHolder.thumbnail);

        bookImageViewHolder.title.setText(book.getTitle());

}

@Override
public BookImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.browse,null);
    BookImageViewHolder bookImageViewHolder = new BookImageViewHolder(view);
    return bookImageViewHolder;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if( booksList == null)
        return 0 ;
    else return booksList.size();
}

public BookRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Book> booksList, Context context) {
    this.booksList = booksList;
    this.context = context;
}
```

}

Comment: "But it allows me to scroll this list twice! I see books repeated" -- my guess is that `List<Book> booksList` has the duplicate entries. I don't see anything in your `BookRecyclerViewAdapter` that is indicative of a problem there.

Comment: @CommonsWare, i think i found out hte problem, it was reading it twice...